# Unlocking "infinite ammo"

Tags: resident-evil-6

I saw a *RE6* gameplay video where the player had infinite ammo unlocked (similar to  *RE5*).

How does this work? Is it something to unlock/activate or a different kind of perk? How can I unlock/activate it? Does it affect achievements?

Comment: Game's already been released?

Comment: I think he's just trying to post as many questions before the game's release so he could get points here in Arqade.

Comment: Why the close?  This game IS out...

Comment: Voted to reopen and then it magically opened. Good timing or does my vote count for several? :P

Comment: @Alex - It had four votes a little while ago, so you were the fifth.

Comment: Like I said, _magic_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to complete all 4 campaigns in order to unlock the ability to purchase it.

You get it as a [skill](http://residentevil.wikia.com/Skills) for each individual weapon type. You can only have 3 skills equipped at anytime and each weapon type costs a significant amount of skill points (prices start at 79k and go up to 99k).

Purchasing and using them does not affect your ability to gain achievements.